# Why does Scala not allow annotations for parameters of anonymous functions?

Tags: scala, annotations, programming-languages

One can add annotations in Scala next to function parameters like this:

```
def foo(@myAnnotation x: Int) = x
```

Is there are a reason for not allowing the following?

```
val bar = { (@myAnnotation x : Int) => x }
```

Comment: You can create your SIP if you need this feature: https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/sip-submission.html First step is to discuss this at https://contributors.scala-lang.org